# Using glBitmap() to create characters (fonts)

Tags: opengl, bitmap

After being pointed to using glBitmap() and this very good tutorial/explanation of its usage from another question for rendering text/numbers in OpenGL: http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter08.html. 
I have another question, not important and immediately needed for any project I'm doing or such, but it's nagging me.

From this piece of code from the link which describes? characters:

```
GLubyte rasters[][13] = {
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x36, 0x36}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0xff, 0x66, 0x66, 0xff, 0x66, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x7e, 0xff, 0x1b, 0x1f, 0x7e, 0xf8, 0xd8, 0xff, 0x7e, 0x18}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x1b, 0xdb, 0x6e, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x76, 0xdb, 0xd8, 0x70}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc6, 0xcf, 0xd8, 0x70, 0x70, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0x6c, 0x38}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x0e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x99, 0x5a, 0x3c, 0xff, 0x3c, 0x5a, 0x99, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xff, 0xff, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xe3, 0xf3, 0xdb, 0xcf, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x78, 0x38, 0x18}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0x7e, 0x07, 0x03, 0x03, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0xff, 0xcc, 0x6c, 0x3c, 0x1c, 0x0c}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x60, 0xcf, 0xdb, 0xd3, 0xdd, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xff, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0xce, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xce, 0xfc}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfc, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfc, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xcf, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xff, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xee, 0xc6, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xd8, 0xf0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xc6, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xdb, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe7, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc7, 0xc7, 0xcf, 0xcf, 0xdf, 0xdb, 0xfb, 0xf3, 0xf3, 0xe3, 0xe3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x6e, 0xdf, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xd8, 0xf0, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0x7e, 0xe0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xff, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x7e, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3c}, 
{0x00, 0x03, 0x03, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x60, 0x60}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x3c}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18}, 
{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x38, 0x30, 0x70}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x03, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0xfc, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1e}, 
{0x7e, 0xc3, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00}, 
{0x38, 0x6c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xf8, 0xf0, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xc6, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x78}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe0, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7e, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0xfc, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x66, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0xc0, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x38, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0f}, 
{0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x0f, 0x1c, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xf0}, 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x8f, 0xf1, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00} 
};
```

At the risk of sounding stupid (I am) - How do the writers of such tutorials know what `0x00` to write in what place in order to describe the bitmaps. I understand they are described from the bottom upwards in this tutorial but how do they know what is it hexadecimal? to write.

I would search this, but I don't even know what `0x00` is referred to or known as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just [two-digit hexadecimal numbers](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_numeral_system).  C uses the `0x` prefix to denote hexadecimal numbers.

Convert those hex numbers to bits and you have your bitmap.

For example a dotted line:

`0xAA` = `170` = [0b10101010](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=0xAA%20in%20binary)

Each `1` will be a white pixel, each `0` black.

So for a 8x8 checkerboard:

```
10101010
01010101
10101010
01010101
10101010
01010101
10101010
01010101
```

You'd have:

```
0xAA, 0x55, 0xAA, 0x55, 0xAA, 0x55, 0xAA, 0x55
```

Every two hex digits correspond to eight bits (or in this case one row) in the bitmap.